# Tracert high latency

Tags: traceroute

I have used tracert command to check local network status, at the second hop I get random- high numbers for latency,(attached file), but when I use ping the total latency has an average of 1ms.

What is the problem?
I really appreciate your help.

BR.
[tracert](https://textuploader.com/dbfm6)

Answer (score -1):

Try the option "-d", i.e. without DNS lookup. It could be that the DNS lookup is causing the delays. For each hop in tracert, it will try to find the fqdn by doing a reverse lookup of the IP address.